# In iOS application for safe login and secure password protection which mechanisms or methods are good for security purpose.? RSA encryption?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, rsa, public-key-encryption

In **iOS application** i have to make **user's login** safe and secure and user can login from **different** iPhones having same application downloaded. Application should work in ***offline*** too. So **which method** should i implement?

I searched and got ***RSA*** **encryption** in which there is **private** and **public** key method but i can't figure out how i implement it in application?whether i **hold both keys** in server and client side or **who get which key**? And how can i make only **one key generation** for every application downloaded? As data should roam securely between **client server** system.

Is there any **other mechanism** which i should consider implementing in my problem?

Comment: It sounds like you need to use an iCloud synchronised keychain item for your login credentials.

Comment: @DavidAtkinson Many users can login on same device and same user can login on many devices?but user login on one device at a time.

Comment: You can't enforce a user only being able to log in to one device at a time if one of the devices is offline - there would be no way to check for other logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to perform any encryption. Just store the passwords in the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html), which has stronger encryption than anything you could possibly implement — as it's integrated into the [Secure Enclave](http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/news/apples-touch-id-a7-secure-enclave-detailed-in-ios-security-document/) which has no public API other than keychain and already uses RSA encryption, among other things to make it even stronger than just that alone.

If the user enables iCloud KeyChain syncing, then the password you store there will be synced across all their devices.

Your application will work offline.

If the user has a weak passcode to unlock their device, then the encryption will not be very good - it can probably be cracked in under an hour (although this information is old, and may not be valid for modern hardware). The best security practice is to disable "Simple Passcode" and use alphabetic characters + digits. It doesn't need to be as strong password, just something short and alphanumeric is fine (the iPhone is a special case, and handles weak passwords better than most security systems). If the user has a finger print scanner available, that can be used to avoid having to type their password in regularly. This is quite secure, contrary to early reports otherwise.

If the devise has no passcode at all, then there is no encryption and it is impossible to implement protection. In that case your only option is to store your secure data on a remote server, and never ever allow the device to access it. Or else just hope nobody steals the phone. Without a passcode/password, it is impossible to store anything securely on an iPhone.

It sounds like you want a single device that will be shared by many users? If that's the case you cannot store the password on the device. It is impossible to achieve security unless there is a passcode and the passcode must be secret, anybody who knows it will be able to bypass any encryption you implement.

Comment: In my app , User can login online or can work in offline mode too on any device which is having this application and there can be many users using same device so is it possible to have many different passwords save in keychain?  So which is the best method to use for saving passwords and other data?

Comment: Keychain is the best way to save passwords. You can store as many as you want.